# Why unicode string is not shown on PyCharm's console?

Tags: python, unicode, pycharm

Environment: Windows 8 + PyCharm 5.0 + Python 2.7.9

```
print "123" # OK

print u"123" # Show empty line on the console?
```

My "File Encodings" already set to UTF-8, and I also 
add:

```
"-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8"
```

in the file "pycharm.exe.vmoptions", but still encounter the issue.

Comment: What are you using for a console? For simple text like your example, the encoding shouldn't matter.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I use Run/Debug console. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Unfortunately I don't know PyCharm so at this point I can't help. Which OS are you using?

Comment: @MarkRansom: Windows 8

Comment: May be font that used in PyCharm's console have no such symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following line in the file "pycharm.exe.vmoptions" can fix the issue:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

It seems to be a bug from PyCharm 5.0...

Answer (score 0):

Like Sean mentioned add the following line to file "pycharm.exe.vmoptions" and also "pycharm64.exe.vmoptions":

`-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Close Pycharm if it's open. Then restart Pycharm5. It's a stupid bug.