# PyCharm 55 UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, pycharm

When I'm trying to print Russian text in console I get �����, despite the fact I set File Encoding and IDE Encoding to UTF-8. This problem have appeared only after updating PyCharm to 5.

Here's the pic of Typing Russian text

[image: Typing russian text]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get PyCharm to display unicode data in its console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188655/how-to-get-pycharm-to-display-unicode-data-in-its-console)

Comment: How are you producing this "russian text"? All we see is an encoding problem in the console. This *could* be the console's fault, or it could be the fault of the app producing the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: go **Settings** -> **Editor** -> **File Encodings** and set **Project Encoding** to *System Default* (It was windows-1251 encoding in my case). It works for me.

Comment: I already had Project Encoding to 1251, but global Encoding was UTF-8. Changed it to 1251 and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If in Windows or Linux add the following lines at the end of the file (Windows)`PYCHARM_HOME/bin/pycharm.exe.vmoptions`, (Linux)`PYCHARM_HOME/bin/pycharm.vmoptions`:

```
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

In OS X Open `Info.plist` located in `/Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents`, locate the tag `<key>VMOptions</key>`, and modify it as follows:

```
 <key>VMOptions</key>
 <string>-Xms16m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=120m
     -Xbootclasspath/p:../lib/boot.jar -ea
     -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
     -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
 </string>
```

Taken from [Configuring Output Encoding](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-output-encoding.html) and [Why unicode string is not shown on PyCharm's console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512828/why-unicode-string-is-not-shown-on-pycharms-console)