# Python 3.4.3 json.dumps() "is not JSON serializable" Error When Converting From Bytes

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, urllib2

So I am having this issue where I am using urllib to GET a JSON response from a server, but when I try to convert the returned `b''` object into JSON, I get an error that says `"...is not JSON serializable"`

Here is my Python code using urllib2 to make a GET request:

```
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    from urllib.error import HTTPError
    import json


    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

    file = Request('http://blahblahblah.com', headers=hdr)

    try:
        page = urlopen(file)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)
        print('')
        return

    content = page.read()
    page.close()


    print(page.info().get_content_charset())  # Returns 'utf-8'
    print(content)
    # print(json.dumps(content))  # Causes 'Not Serializable' Error
    # print(content.decode('utf-8')  # Causes 'UnicodeEncodeError' Error
```

Here is the response I am getting from the server:

```
b'{"game":{"id":1,"name":"Thief II: The Metal Age","slug":"thief-ii-the-metal-age","release_date":"2000-03-21","created_at":"2011-02-13 00:20:38 +0000","updated_at":"2016-03-15 19:41:25 +0000","alternative_names":[{"name":"Thief II: \xd0\xad\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x85\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0","comment":"Russian title"},{"name":"Dark Project II: The Metal Age","comment":"German title"},{"name":"Dark Project II: L\'Age de M\xc3\xa9tal","comment":"French title"}],"genres":[{"name":"Shooter"}],"themes":[{"name":"Action"},{"name":"Fantasy"},{"name":"Stealth"}],"rating":9.131189346313477,"release_dates":[{"platform_name":"Microsoft Windows","release_date":"2000-03-21"}],"companies":[{"id":4,"developer":false,"publisher":true,"name":"Eidos Interactive"},{"id":3,"developer":true,"publisher":false,"name":"Looking Glass Studios"},{"id":26,"developer":false,"publisher":true,"name":"Square Enix"}],"cover":{"url":"//res.cloudinary.com/igdb/image/upload/t_cover_small/qagoforxr6tofvpmgy9g.png","width":612,"height":650,"id":"qagoforxr6tofvpmgy9g"},"screenshots":[{"url":"//res.cloudinary.com/igdb/image/upload/t_screenshot_med/z0b9mqcqbtmnnxigekjc.jpg","title":"Microsoft Windows Title Screen","width":640,"height":480,"id":"z0b9mqcqbtmnnxigekjc"},{"url":"//res.cloudinary.com/igdb/image/upload/t_screenshot_med/puvydf5d6v0zirxfhzpg.jpg","title":"Microsoft Windows Ingame Screen","width":640,"height":480,"id":"puvydf5d6v0zirxfhzpg"}],"videos":[{"title":"Trailer","uid":"9C543B6uJ88"}]}}'
```

I have read elsewhere that I have to first convert the response to a `str` or use `utf-8` encoding, but when I try to replace `print(content)` with `print(content.decode('utf-8')`, I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 231-235: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using Python 3.4.3

Comment: `urllib2` was removed in python 3. I assume you are using `urlib.request` then.

Comment: Yes - I just updated my code to reflect that

Comment: I was able to `print(content.decode('utf-8'))` your data without a problem. I think your problem happens when printing the decoded string to your terminal. What does `sys.getdefaultencoding()` say? My guess is that `data = json.loads(content.decode(page.info().get_content_charset()))` will work but a following `print(data)` will fail.

Comment: `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns `utf-8`

Comment: Another perfectly good theory down the drain.

Comment: I know! I stumbled across a lot of these solutions before creating this thread, that is why I am so confused... I updated my code for you with access to the test API, so if that helps let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually figured it out - the problem was that my IDE (Pycharm 5.0) for some reason could not handle outputting `utf-8` in the IDE console, which caused an error. The solution was to add the following line of code to the `pycharm.exe.vmpoptions` file in my windows computer:

`-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Credit goes to another user for finding the same solution when they had a similar issue:

> Source: [Why unicode string is not shown on PyCharm's console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512828/why-unicode-string-is-not-shown-on-pycharms-console)

Answer (score 2):

The server returns bytes (it was string in python 2 as I remember) and I can see it's utf-8, so you need to decode it to unicode

for example this works:

```
print(json.loads(content.decode()))
```

Here is a link where you can find some info about it:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/unicode.html

You might need to use strict mode, check the how to

Comment: ...and you want to `json.loads`

Comment: I noticed that works as well, but the issue is that I need to extract values from the JSON response, but when I try to use `json.loads()` after the code you supplied, I am met with the `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap'` error again! Any ideas?

Comment: pardon, @tdelaney, but it still work for me with loads as well.
I'm using Python 3.5.0 and standard json, which is import json.

Is blahblahblah.com is correct address so I can check it by myself?

Comment: It works for me too. I think you could do `json.loads(content.decode(encoding="utf-8"))` so that you aren't dependent on the default encoding (`sys.getdefaultencoding()`).